# In R, how can I add an additional column to a table object?

Tags: r

I called the table() function on a data.frame.

This is the output.

```
Browse[1]> x

   II       III        IV [Unknown]         V 
    1         9        10         3         1 

Browse[1]> y

   I       III        IV [Unknown]         V 
   3         12       15         10        2
```

The problem is that one of the columns is not shown because there are 0 elements there. Thus, when I plot this table on a barplot, nothing is shown for that column. How can I add a specific column with the number 0 to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, `table()` returns a named vector. I can construct it by:

```
x <- c(II = 1, III = 9, IV = 10, "[Unknown]" = 9, V = 1)
# II     III      IV [Unknown]       V 
#  1       9      10         9       1
```

A named vector is still a vector, where you only have elements not columns. We can use `c()` to concatenate:

```
x <- c(I = 0, x)
#  I      II     III      IV [Unknown]       V 
#  0       1       9      10         9       1
```

---

Generally, we can use `append()`. For example, with your `y`:

```
y <- c(I = 3, III = 12, IV = 15, "[Unknown]" = 10, V = 2)
#    I       III        IV [Unknown]         V 
#    3        12        15        10         2
```

We can do:

```
y <- append(y, 0, 1)  ## insert value 0 after y[1]
#    I                 III        IV [Unknown]         V 
#    3         0        12        15        10         2
```

But we have to set names via a separate step:

```
names(y)[2] <- "II"
#    I        II       III        IV [Unknown]         V 
#    3         0        12        15        10         2
```

---

**Edit**

Thanks to @thelatemail, for your `y` we could simple do:

```
append(y, c(II = 0), 1)
#    I        II       III        IV [Unknown]         V 
#    3         0        12        15        10         2
```

Comment: Another one of my objects has II = 0, so I need to add that in. Is there a way to insert between two columns?

Comment: I have another table. I call it y in this case. y, instead of column "I", is missing column "II"

Comment: How can I insert between two columns?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to have the names in a separate step - `append(y, c('II'=0), after=1)` for instance.